# Why does Log.d(TAG,"B1: Offers: Size:"+ it.size +" "+ it.forEach{a -> "My Office: "+ a.offerTags.toString()} ) return error result?

Tags: android, kotlin

`Log.d(TAG,"B0: Offers: Size:"+ it.size +"  My: "+ it[0].offerTags.toString() )` return correct result.

But why does `Log.d(TAG,"B1: Offers: Size:"+ it.size +"  "+ it.forEach{a -> "My Office: "+ a.offerTags.toString()} )`  return error result ?

BTW, I'm very strange why `kotlin.Unit` is to return?

**Kotlin Source Code**

```
val offerToken = offers?.let {
            Log.d(TAG,"B0: Offers: Size:"+ it.size +"  My: "+ it[0].offerTags.toString() )
            Log.d(TAG,"B1: Offers: Size:"+ it.size +"  "+ it.forEach{a -> "My Office: "+ a.offerTags.toString()} )          
            leastPricedOfferToken(it)
        }
```

**Result**

```
B0: Offers: Size:1  My: [yearlypremium]
B1: Offers: Size:1  kotlin.Unit
```

Comment: Why is `kotlin.Unit`shown ? because that's the result of the execution (that's the result of what you've done), which is basically showing that you're just calling a method which is returning nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the forEach function iterates over the elements but doesn't explicitly return any value.

The logging process incurs overhead for each message. Using a loop within the log amplifies this effect, potentially impacting performance so this approach is inefficient.

A better way to approach this logic

```kotlin
    val offersString = it.joinToString(separator = ", ") { a -> a.offerTags.toString()}
    Log.d(TAG, "B1: Offers: Size:${it.size}. My Offers: $offersString")
```

This will join all the strings aka offerTags with this separator ", "

Comment: Thanks!  The issue will launch in the usage of forEach with the lambda expression, just like  `val offerToken = offers?.let {...}`,  right?

Comment: @HelloCW Yes, just like this                                                                                      `val offerToken = offers?.let {
            Log.d(TAG,"B0: Offers: Size:"+ it.size +"  My: "+ it[0].offerTags.toString() )
                    val offersString = it.joinToString(separator = ", ") { a ->                                        a.offerTags.toString()}
            Log.d(TAG, "B1: Offers: Size:${it.size}. My Offers: $offersString")
            leastPricedOfferToken(it)
        }`